# How do I get the regex matched value using Boost.Regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

I'm trying to extract the domain from a URL. Following is an example script.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main () {

  std::string url = "http://mydomain.com/randompage.php";
  boost::regex exp("^https?://([^/]*?)/");
  std::cout << regex_search(url,exp);

}
```

How do I print the matched value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the overload of regex_search that takes a match_results object.  In your case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main () {    
  std::string url = "http://mydomain.com/randompage.php";
  boost::regex exp("^https?://([^/]*?)/");
  boost::smatch match;
  if (boost::regex_search(url, match, exp))
  {
    std::cout << std::string(match[1].first, match[1].second);
  }    
}
```

Edit: Corrected begin, end ==> first, second

Comment: I'm getting errors when I compile this.

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11: error: ‘const struct boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ has no member named ‘begin’
main.cpp:11: error: ‘const struct boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ has no member named ‘end’

Comment: My fault.  I'll fix it.  It should be first and second, not begin() and end().